# Nested switches or multiple functions, what would be a better design?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, switch-statement

I have a large method that looks something like this

```
List<Hotel> findAvailHotels(Provider provider, Method method, List<String> codes) {
    switch (provider) {
        case PROVIDER_1:
            //TODO Do common things to provider 1
            switch (method) {
                case HOTEL_CODE:
                    break;
                case DESTINATION_CODE:
                    break;
                case GEO:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case PROVIDER_2:
            switch (method) {
                case HOTEL_CODE:
                    break;
                case DESTINATION_CODE:
                    break;
                case GEO:
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
```

So each time I need to add a provider I'll need to add a case to that provider and then repeat the `method` switch for this new provider.

I got a suggestion from a fellow that should be split into methods for each `method` so for example instead of the above, it'll be

```
List<Hotel> findAvailHotelsByHotelCode(Provider provider, List<String> codes) {
    switch (provider) {
        case PROVIDER_1:
            //TODO Do common things to provider 1
            break;
        case PROVIDER_2:
            break;
    }

List<Hotel> findAvailHotelsByDestinationCode(Provider provider, List<String> codes) {
    switch (provider) {
        case PROVIDER_1:
            //TODO Do common things to provider 1
            break;
        case PROVIDER_2:
            break;
    }

List<Hotel> findAvailHotelsByGeo(Provider provider, List<String> codes) {
    switch (provider) {
        case PROVIDER_1:
            //TODO Do common things to provider 1
            break;
        case PROVIDER_2:
            break;
    }
```

---

*Personal thoughts*: Maybe splitting into multiple methods makes it more cleaner but if I need to do common stuff to `PROVIDER_1` (despite the `method`) then this common thing will need to be repeated/duplicated in each method (as indicated by the `//TODO`s in the above code) which kinda means more lines of code but that's a bit irrelevant maybe.

I'd like to hear some thoughts about this, which would you consider more readable and more clean? Any better alternatives?

---

**edit**: To give more context, I work with hotel providers.. most providers have 3 common methods of search (hotel_code, destination_code, geo).. from outside this method I can do a `hotel_code` search for all providers (by looping over the Provider enum and calling the method for each provider with `hotel_code` enum param).. or I can do it to a specific provider.

Comment: Not nice, but doable without the switch statements: Reflection. On the other hand it sounds like you could solve that problem by using inheritance. Collect common information in the baseclass and put the altering part in the child classes

Comment: @ParkerHalo use of *reflection* should be the verry last resort to do something in Java!

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Thats why i wrote _"Not nice"_... Thats also why I didn't make an answer out of it and suggested inheritance/polymorphism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Question is still a little too abstract to suggest a "best" solution, but Timothy is right so far - in either case you can use polimorphism.

I suggest Strategy pattern because you define the broad structure by using an interface and create an a dedicated class for every single algorithm (provider in your case).

This has at least two advantages:

1. You have an easy to oversee List of algorithms in the form of classes.
2. You can replace the outer switch by a loop through your strategy objects.

Hmm - since you asked for it - here is some example code (a little large though ...)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HotelStuff {

  private static class Hotel{/* does whatever ...*/}

  private enum SearchMethod{
    HOTELCODE,
    DESTINATIONCODE,
    GEOCODE
  }

  private interface Providable{
    List<Hotel> findAvailHotels(SearchMethod method, List<String> codes); 
  }

  private static class Provider1 implements Providable{
    @Override
    public List<Hotel> findAvailHotels(SearchMethod method, List<String> codes) {
        // TODO create the list ...
        return null;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Providable> providers = new ArrayList<Providable>();
    providers.add(new Provider1());
    // providers.add(new Provider2 .. and so on     
    List<String> codes = Arrays.asList("123","456");
    SearchMethod method = SearchMethod.GEOCODE;
    List<Hotel> availableHotels = findAvailHotels(providers, method, codes);
  }

  public static List<Hotel> findAvailHotels(List<Providable> providers, SearchMethod method, List<String> codes) {
    List<Hotel> result = new ArrayList<Hotel>();
    List<Hotel> partResult;
    for(Providable provider: providers) {
        partResult = provider.findAvailHotels(method, codes);
        result.addAll(partResult);
    }
    return result;
  }

}
```

Of course you should implement the classes in seperate files - i just put them into one file to shorten it.

Comment: I edited the code above and added more context to make it more clear

Comment: Well thats that then.Since your "findAvailHotels..." methods already have the same signature you can unite all three to just one method with a method parameter and use this one as part of your interface.

Comment: Would you be kind to throw a simple example whenever you get the time? Because it will make me understand more clearly. Thanks

Comment: Thanks.. I ended up going with this approach, basically a combination of strategy pattern and a factory method. I appreciate all other answers but I'm accepting this as it's most comprehensive for me. Thanks to all others for the help

Answer (score 1):

Unless your `switch` statement is in a *factory* you should better use **polymorphism**.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into both the visitor pattern and double dispatch.

The Gang of Four defines the Visitor as:

> Represent an operation to be performed on elements of an object structure. Visitor lets you define a new operation without changing the classes of the elements on which it operates.

In your case *Provider* is the object and *Method* is the operation.

Double dispatch is useful in situations where the choice of computation depends on the runtime types of its arguments. In your case: you want to do something based on the type of *Provider* and *Method*.